# VSCode Open external terminal and focus on it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use ctrl+shift+c to open the external terminal on vscode, but it does not focus on external terminal. It always behind the vscode. I want to know how to open the external terminal and "focus" on it.

Comment: I found this question helpful simply for the noting `ctrl+shift+c` command opens an external terminal. I couldn't find this detail elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

````
{
        "key": "ctrl+;",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
``` to complete the settings
````

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue with using ctrl+shift+c to open the external terminal in VSCode. Until the beginning of this year (2024), it worked fine for me, but then I started experiencing the same problem you described. After debugging the source code of VSCode, I identified the root cause, which stems from the implementation of the detached: true flag, as highlighted in this commit: [GitHub Commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/9af00bdd834a4e9dc2f199251cdeeb4e9700f2f2).

It seems that passing detached: true is causing the issue, as seen in this snippet from the VSCode source code:

```js
const child = spawner.spawn(command, cmdArgs, { cwd, env, detached: true }); // Current implementation - no focus
const child = spawner.spawn(command, cmdArgs, { cwd, env }); // Previous implementation - focuses on terminal
```

To simplify, here's a basic version of how VSCode opens the external terminal in Windows:

```js
import cp from 'child_process';
import path from 'path';

const exec = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe';
const cwd = 'D:\\Code';
const command = 'cmd.exe';

const basename = path.basename(exec, '.exe').toLowerCase();

const cmdArgs = ['/c', 'start', '/wait'];
if (exec.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
  // The "" argument is the window title. Without this, exec doesn't work when the path
  // contains spaces
  cmdArgs.push('""');
}
cmdArgs.push(exec);

// Current implementation - does not focus on terminal
cp.spawn(command, cmdArgs, { cwd, detached: true });

// Previous implementation - focuses on terminal
cp.spawn(command, cmdArgs, { cwd });
```

By removing the detached: true flag, the external terminal should regain focus as desired. However this can cause other problems, we should create an issue on vscode repo to ask more about this.

Answer (score -1):

assign a hotkey to focus to the terminal.

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+;",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
    },
```

in my case

Comment: This doesn't open external terminal and fokus on them