# Is it possible to set up VS Code to run code in an external terminal Window instead of the integrated terminal/output windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to use the Atom code editor and one of the features I liked about this editor was that when I executed python code it would bring up an external CMD window where I would interact with the code, if input was required, and receive the results.

I have moved to VS Code as Atom is no longer supported and I have looked on here and with Google, but I do not seem to be able to get VS Code to behave in this fashion :(

I am wondering if any of the folks on here with more experience with VS code can advise if what I am looking to do is possible or do I just have to suck it up and use the integrated terminal/output panes at the bottom of the window?

Any advise would be very much appreciated.

I have tried in the "Configure Terminal Settings" to change from Integrated to External, but this has made no difference.

Comment: Does this get you part of the way there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084823/vscode-open-external-terminal-and-focus-on-it

Comment: @Vin No, not really. This gives me a new external terminal, but if I want to run a python file I need to type "python <file>.py". What I was looking for is for when I click on the "run" button that a external terminal opens with my python program running in it. This was the behavior with the Atom editor and seems to be the default also in Visual Studio. But does not appear to work in VS Code :(